# Disable click fot td for particular column using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

I have tried to use Jquery to click a table row to go to a new page. But my last column has a button. For which clicking on the edge takes it to a new page. Anyway to disable the td onclick for that column. I tried using `onclick='event.stopPropagation();return false;'` but that would disable the button too.
My Jquery code below.

```
$(".myTable").on("click", "td", function(){
var issueid = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2) input").val();
window.location = 'viewminissues.jsp?issue_id='+issueid;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the click event from the button propagates up the DOM to the `tr` which then transfers the page.

To fix this you could call `stopPropagation()` within the button event handler:

```js
$(".myTable").on("click", "td", function() {
  var issueid = $(this).closest('tr').data('issue');      
  console.log('Transferring to: viewminissues.jsp?issue_id=' + issueid);
  //window.location.assign('viewminissues.jsp?issue_id=' + issueid);
});

$('.myTable').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Perform button action...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable">
  <tr data-issue="1">
    <td>Foo bar</td>
    <td><button>Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-issue="2">
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td><button>Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be handled in two ways:

1. Try adding `event.preventDefault()` along with `event.stopPropagation()`.
2. Add a disabled class on the td element manually and then handle further scenarios with `hasClass('disabled'`) check.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude the last `<td>` from the `click()` event using `:not(:last)` like this:

```
$(".myTable").on("click", "td:not(:last)", function() {
  var issueid = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2) input").val();
  window.location = 'viewminissues.jsp?issue_id=' + issueid;
});
```